# Can't find solution for Linq to SQL Select first letter and distinct statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following function. My goal is to show the first letters of Course subjects.
The error that I get is

> Cannot implicitly convert type ''         `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>`' 
>   to '`System.Collections.Generic.List`...'

**my code**

```
public List<SchoolSubject> GetTutoringSubjectsLetters()
{
    List<SchoolSubject> result = new List<SchoolSubject>();
    using (JewroOnlineDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
    {
        var subjects = (from s in dc.SchoolSubjects
                        select new { s.SubjectName }).Distinct();
        return subjects;
    }
}
```

How do I fix this? 
Thank you.

Comment: `new { s.SubjectName }` is not a `SchoolSubject`

Comment: @Albert, Have you tried with our solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public List<string> GetTutoringSubjectsLetters()
{
    using (JewroOnlineDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
    {
        return dc.SchoolSubjects.Select(s => s.SubjectName.Substring(0, 1)).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to call `ToList` if you want to convert the result of the linq query to a `List<T>`, however, unless you *need* to dynamically add or remove items from the result set, converting it to a list is probably not necessary.

Also, if you just want to return a string containing the first letter, there's no need to return an object (either a `SchoolSubject` or an anonymous type). You can just return a set of `string`s as the result.

I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTutoringSubjectsLetters()
{
    using (JewroOnlineDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
    {
        return (from s in dc.SchoolSubjects
                select s.SubjectName.Remove(1))
               .Distinct();
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer fluent syntax:

```
return dc.SchoolSubjects.Select(s => s.SubjectName.Remove(1)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Why s.Remove(1) required? The question is, it should get the distinct first letters only. Can you correct me please.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Sorry, that should have been `s.SubjectName.Remove(1)`, which returns the first letter in a string.

Comment: Great learning from you. Remove (index) [The zero-based position to begin deleting characters.] which is similar to Substring(0,1). am i correct Thanks.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Yes, `.Remove(x)` is identical to `.Substring(0, x)`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for a nice solution.